# Chrome App with Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome-app

I'd like to write a chrome app in python.  Most of it would involve communication with hardware over pyusb/chrome.usb.  I have an existing protocol written in python (hence the interest) and would like to just tack on some basic buttons.

Is there any kind of path forward for this crazy idea?  Any transcompilers or support otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either compile and distribute [CPython](https://www.python.org/download/) with [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) or [Google Native Client](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client) or use something like [pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/).

To do USB you're going to need to go through JavaScript (chrome.usb). The different methods have different ways of doing that. pyusb is not going to work without writing some sort of wrapper.